# Rename file to take name in of parent folder

Tags: regex, windows, cygwin

I need to name files in a directory so that they take the name of the parent folder and then increment by 1.

So I have

```
myfolder
-- myfirstfile.txt
-- mysecondfile2.txt
```

I need it to be:

```
myfolder
--myfolder1.txt
--myfolder2.txt
```

Any tips?

Comment: Why did you tag this `regex`?

Comment: Thought I might be able to use a regex with rename. I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ pwd
/tmp/stack

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ ls 
aTMP    bTMP    cTMP    dTMP    eTMP    fTMP    gTMP    hTMP    iTMP    jTMP    kTMP    lTMP    mTMP    nTMP    oTMP    pTMP    qTMP    rTMP    sTMP    tTMP    uTMP    vTMP    wTMP    xTMP    yTMP    zTMP

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ NUM=1;for i in `ls -1`;do mv $i `pwd`/$i$NUM.txt; ((NUM++)); done

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ ls
aTMP1.txt   cTMP3.txt   eTMP5.txt   gTMP7.txt   iTMP9.txt   kTMP11.txt  mTMP13.txt  oTMP15.txt  qTMP17.txt  sTMP19.txt  uTMP21.txt  wTMP23.txt  yTMP25.txt
bTMP2.txt   dTMP4.txt   fTMP6.txt   hTMP8.txt   jTMP10.txt  lTMP12.txt  nTMP14.txt  pTMP16.txt  rTMP18.txt  tTMP20.txt  vTMP22.txt  xTMP24.txt  zTMP26.txt
```

If you have space in file names, change `IFS` variable accordingly.

How `IFS` affects:

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ ls -1
a STACK
b STACK
c STACK
d STACK
e STACK
f STACK
```

Before setting `IFS` to `'\n'`:

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ for i in `ls -1`; do echo $i ; done
a
STACK
b
STACK
c
STACK
d
STACK
e
STACK
f
STACK
```

After setting `IFS` to `'\n'`:

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ TMPIFS=$IFS;IFS='\n'; for i in `ls -1`; do echo $i ; done; IFS=$TMPIFS
a STACK
b STACK
c STACK
d STACK
e STACK
f STACK
```

Comment: ar eyou running that from bash shell? I get: mv: unknown option -- l.   When I remove the option and just try ls, I get: mv: cannot stat `ls': No such file or directory

Comment: problem I am having is I have spaces is in my file names. Any ideas?

Comment: In bash(Linux), we can use `IFS` variable so that you can change default field separator to `'\n'` from a `space`.

Comment: you are not getting folder name in file name in your solution.  Also pwd will give you entire path. Not sure what is going on there.

Comment: check first `pwd` output. I am running script from that `pwd`

Answer (score 0):

I just used python to do this...

```
import os

...

def get_files_in_directory(rootDir=rootDirectory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown='true'):
        counter = 0;
        for file in files:
            #I only wanted to rename files ending with .mod
            ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower();
            if (ext == '.mod'):
                # here is how I got the parent folder name 
                folder = os.path.relpath(root, rootDir);
                counter+=1;
                newfilename = folder + '_' + counter + ".mod";
                os.rename(root + '\\' +  file, root + '\\' + newfilename);
```